# Interfaces in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, interface

Let's say I have the following structure inside my Ruby project (actually, Ruby On Rails 5, but I guess this is more about Ruby than RoR5):

```
main.rb
greeter.rb
impl/dog.rb
impl/cat.rb
config.yaml
```

How would I implement an interface in 'greeter.rb' in such a way so I could get to see a 'bau bau!' in the output if I run the following (pseudo)code:

```
//main.rb
include greeter.rb
greet()

//config.yaml
greeter = Dog

//dog.rb
def greet()
    print 'bau bau!'
end

//cat.rb
def greet()
    print 'miau!'
end
```

Comment: Use the [`require`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-require) method.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 that's pseudocode. include vs require is out of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

While this might be the way you're thinking about solving the problem, from the perspective of Ruby it's totally wrong. What you want is something like this:

```
# lib/animal.rb
class Animal
  def self.of_type(type, *args)
    case (type)
    when 'cat'
      Cat.new(*args)
    when 'dog'
      Dog.new(*args)
    end
  end
end

# Explicitly load subclasses
require_relative('./cat')
require_relative('./dog')
```

Now that loads in two specific sub-classes that implement the specific behaviours:

```
# lib/cat.rb
class Cat < Animal
  def greet
    "Mew!"
  end
end

# lib/dog.rb
class Dog < Animal
  def greet
    "Woof!"
  end
end
```

You can write a simple test script to verify this, but using `test/unit`, `rspec` or Minitest is even better:

```
# test/example.rb
require_relative('../lib/animal')

Animal.of_type('dog').greet
# => "Woof!"
```

Note that in Ruby methods with no arguments have their brackets removed, they're not required and tradition holds they be omitted for simplicity. Likewise, `lib/` is where most library "implementations" are stored.

There's generally no `main.rb` file as there's generally no `main` method. You just set up things in either a `bin/` type script, or as part of something else, like your test framework or web environment.

Comment: This way my "main" code will have to know about 'dog' and 'cat' and whenever I want to switch between them I'll need to change my code. Is there a way I can export that so it can be configured from a yaml file?

Comment: You don't need to change your code. That's what the factory method `of_type` helps you do. Given a string it returns the right type of object. You can save that in YAML or anything else if you want.

Comment: Yes, but I'd be used that 'of_type' method all over my code, so I'll need to change that whenever I want to change dog for cat, right?

Comment: Just pass in a different parameter. If you want, you can make the `Animal` class read the YAML file for you and load the right subclass automatically.